# c++/g++ --- Compilation Error.. fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, compiler-errors, g++

i'm like working client-server application..

I'm trying to run the server - CountryServer.c file..

i tried with g++ and gcc and i got compilation errors.. i even googled and got answers.. sadly i still got the same errors..

with gcc
[image: Gcc Compilation Error]

[image: G++ Error]

oh, i even also tried to enable `std=c++11` 
and `std=c++0x` but it says no input files.. >.<

i enabled using this command:

```
gcc -std=c++11
```

and also tried this other enabled commands:

```
g++ -std=c++1 CountryServer.c -o CountryServer
```

and 
`g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 CountryServer.c -o CountryServer`
 for both `0x` & `11`

andd,i've also checked which version has the iostream and also checked the gcc or g++ version >.<

i really dont understand and dont know what other ways/solutions/methods.. 
please help me! thanks ! :D

Comment: What error do you get for `g++ -std=c++11 -o CountryServer CountryServer.c`?

Answer (score 0):

for iostream error,
can you please try compiling with g++

or
compiling gcc with option -lstdc++

gcc  -o  -lstdc++

Comment: it still shows the same iostream error.. i compiled with gcc.. this is what i typed - `gcc -lstdc++ CountryServer.c -o CountryServer`

Comment: if i compile with g++ it show the requiring the compiler and asking to enable -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 message.. im not using gnu btw..

Comment: @NewbProgrammer _"im not using gnu btw"_ Uhm, what? You are using the GNU C/C++ compiler, that's what's gcc/g++ actually is.

Comment: Can you please tell us your compiler version ?

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2